# Converting difference between 2 dates to days in java 7

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat, timeunit

I want to compare 2 dates in java and need to convert the difference between the 2 dates to days

```
//Setting up date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2019, 5, 16);
Date d = cal.getTime();
```

Output would be something like this :    Sun Jun 16 11:04:57 UTC 2019

```
//Getting the current date instance
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d1 = cal1.getTime();
```

Output would be something like this :    Mon Jul 08 11:04:57 UTC 2019

Need to get the difference between d & d1 in days.

Thanks in advance for taking your time to provide solution

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm using java-7

Comment: Use the new time and date methods. Calendar should never be used in new code.

Comment: Can you switch to java 8 or above?

Comment: This is really complicated to get right with the old `Calendar` class. Do consider [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport to Java 6 and 7 of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. With it it will be a piece of cake and give very readable code.

Comment: Answer using ThreeTen Backport: `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JUNE, 16), LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")))`. Just now gave 22. Please factor out into an appropriate number of lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you just have to do simple math.

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(2010, 7, 23);
end.set(2010, 8, 26);
Date startDate = start.getTime();
Date endDate = end.getTime();
long startTime = startDate.getTime();
long endTime = endDate.getTime();
long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
System.out.println("The difference between "+
  dateFormat.format(startDate)+" and "+
  dateFormat.format(endDate)+" is "+
  diffDays+" days.");
```

This will not work when crossing daylight savings time (or leap seconds) and might as well not give the expected results when using different times of day. You can modify it like this:

```
start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (int)diffDays);
while (start.before(end)) {
    start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    diffDays++;
}
while (start.after(end)) {
    start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    diffDays--;
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
public static long getDifferenceDays(Date d, Date d1) {
    long diff = d1.getTime() - d.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```